# Failed to Load Response Data: No data found for resource with given Identifier in Chrome when uploading invalid file in NestJS REST Controller

Tags: rest, google-chrome, user-interface, file-upload, nestjs

I have a NestJS REST controller that accepts a file as input. To validate the file extension, we have introduced an interceptor. If the file extension is not .xls, the interceptor throws an INVALID_FILE_FORMAT (400 error) and the request is halted. We have integrated a UI with this API for file uploads.

The issue we are facing is specific to Google Chrome. When a user selects an invalid file (e.g., test.doc, while the API expects only .xls files), we see the following error in the network tab's response section: "Failed to Load Response Data: No data found for resource with given Identifier."

Interestingly, the API works as expected when tested with Postman using an invalid file.

Could someone please help us resolve this issue?

Note: This issue occurs only in Google Chrome.

Note: One more thing i found is it is happening when we upload a file with larger size (approximately more than 400 kb).

Thank you!